# Populating a pulldown with a different field, not the primary key

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make a form that lets you define a location.  This location has a `title`, an autonumbered `ID` (the key for the table), and it may have a `region`, which is the location it's contained in.  Some example data:

```
 ID  title        region
 --  -----        ------
 1   Asia
 2   Mongolia     1
 3   Kazakhstan   1
 4   Astana       3
 5   China        1
 6   Europe
```

On the form (where you can define a new location), I'd like to have a pulldown where the user can select the region by a different field (such as `title`) instead of by `ID`.  How can I do this in Access 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop a combo box on your form, set the datasource to this query:

```
SELECT id, title FROM location ORDER BY title
```

Set the `ColumnCount` property to 2 and set the first column width to zero

Bind the control to your region field, and there you have it, a nice recursive data structure.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you're saying I should have one table for locations, and another table for those locations that are used as regions?  It seems like storing the data in two places is not the best idea.

Comment: Oh i see now. Well in that case change the datasource of the combobox to something like 'SELECT id,title FROM location where region IS NULL'

Comment: What's the purpose of the WHERE clause?  It seems like that would limit it to only those locations that aren't part of another location.

Comment: Apologies. That is what I assumed by the sample data. Leaving the WHERE clause is fine and will give you a nice  recursive structure.